# Can't delete theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm getting an error when I try to delete a theme. It says I deleted the theme but when I refresh the themes page it is still showing up.

[image]

Comment: What a page do you refresh? Who says you about deletion? Can you please describe it in your question by editing, not in a comment. And what you are tried to do?

Comment: This is on the themes page. I clicked on the installed them and then clicked the delete button.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a permissions problem with your files. Can you login to your server via SFTP (or FTP)? You should then go to /wp-content/themes folder and find the theme you want to delete in its own folder. You can then delete it there if you have permissions, or change the files to give yourself ownership first and then do it.

Comment: well, if you can see it but not delete it (in SFTP) that is probably a good sign. If you don't have shell access or the correct permissions, you may need to ask your hosting provider to delete it for you.

Comment: I could delete it from SFTP but not from the WordPress admin panel.